# Victure AC600 camera not working

Tags: webcam, camera

I have a Victure AC600 camera (https://www.govicture.com/ac600) and I use Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. The camera doesn't work correctly with neither cheese nor Camorama. In both cases, all I see is a static image, what was captured when I connected the camera.

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 046d:c313 Logitech, Inc. Internet 350 Keyboard 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 192f:0416 Avago Technologies, Pte. ADNS-5700 Optical Mouse Controller (3-button) 
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 2aad:6353 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

When running `camorama` in the terminal, I see:

```
Gtk-Message: 19:30:24.558: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
(camorama:4685): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:30:24.691: GtkSpinButton: setting an adjustment with non-zero page size is deprecated
(camorama:4685): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 19:30:25.077: cannot retrieve class for invalid (unclassed) type '<invalid>'
```

And when running `cheese`:

```
(cheese:4704): cheese-WARNING **: 19:31:34.742: A lot of buffers are being dropped.: gstbasesink.c(2902): gst_base_sink_is_too_late (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstViewfinderBin:vf-bin/ClutterGstVideoSink:cluttergstvideosink0:
There may be a timestamping problem, or this computer is too slow.
```

What else can I do?

Comment: This is largely an English site - you can use google translate to assist you.  Also, a command such as lsusb, can be written as `LANG=C lsusb`, and the output will be in english.

Comment: Your last error message, from Cheese, says the computer may be to slow.  Can you test the camera on another system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Le he quitado la tarjeta micro-SD y ya funciona correctamente.

I have removed the micro-SD card and it is already working correctly.